# Serialize model without relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have two models:

```
@Entity
class ModelA {
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "modelA")
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<ModelB> modelBs = new ArrayList<ModelB>();
  ...
}

@Entity
class ModelB {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "modela_id")
  @JsonBackReference
  private ModelA modela;
  ...
}
```

And a REST/Resource controller for ModelA which has a list method:

```
@GetMapping("list")
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<ModelA> list() {
  ArrayList<ModelA> modelas = new ArrayList();

  for (ModelA moa : modelARepository.findAll()) {
    modelas.add(moa);
  }

  return modelas;
}
```

Now by default the response from that controller will contain a JSON array of ModelA objects but those will also contain ModelB. Is there a way to pick which relations you want serialized and when ?

Coming from Django/Laravel I would be solving this with dedicated serializes for instance I would have a `ModelAWithRelatiionsSerializer` where I would serializer ModelA + all of it's relations or `ModelAWithModelBSerializer` which would return ModelA serialized with one level of ModelB etc.

I know I can juse ignore annotation to not include it but that's really not the same and I saw nothing regarding serializes in Spring packages. What's the best or optimal way of doing this ?

Comment: You can use views (https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring), or DTOs.

Comment: There has to be a clear separation of concerns. Same entity is used in multiple usecases and only relevant data should be exposed. Hence it is always best practice to use DTOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is moving from Laravel(PHP), Django(Python), Rails(Ruby):

I created a package `serializers` in which I have a serializer class for each of my models.

```
public class UserSerializer {

  // Default user values
  public interface User {}

  // User values with users posts
  public interface UserWithPosts extends User {}  

}
```

Now in your model what you do is annotate fields to which serializers they belong to:

```
@Entity  
class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @JsonView(UserSerializer.User.class)
  private Long id;

  @JsonView(UserSerializer.User.class)
  private String username;

  @JsonView(UserSerializer.User.class)
  private String email;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  @JsonManagedReference  // This prevents infinite loop  
  @JsonView(UserSerializer.UserWithPosts.class)  
  private List<Post> posts;

  // .. getters and setters bellow
}
```

In your controller you than annotate your methods with `@JsonView(..)` as to which serializer you want to use.

```
@RestController  
@RequestMapping("users")  
public class UsersController {

  private UserRepository userRepository;

  public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }  

  /**
   * In list method we only want users default values to keep the payload smaller.
   */
  @GetMapping("list")
  @JsonView(UserSerializer.User.class)  
  public @ResponseBody ArrayList<User> list() {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
      users.add(user);
    }

    return users;
  }


  /**
   * In this method we are only fetching a single user so payload is smaller so we can add the users posts as well. You could also toggle this with a url filter/parameter.  
   */
  @GetMapping("show")
  @JsonView(UserSerializer.UserWithPosts.class)  
  public @ResponseBody ArrayList<User> show(@RequestParam(name = "id", required = true) Long id) {
    return userRepository.findOne(id):
  }

}
```

**Configuration!** This was pretty easy to understand however when I first did it none of the examples/tutorials told/showed that you need to update the configuration as well. If you don't do it than you will have a problem with serializing your relations the serializers will still work however you would get something like this in your JSON response:

```
...
"posts": [
  {},
  {},
  {},..
]
...
```

So it would return a JSON object for each post user has but no values to fix this i created `config` package added a `WebConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().defaultViewInclusion(true).build();
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper));
    }

}
```

You can also do this in XML configuration. But I personally prefer using Java class based configuration. It would be great if spring documentation included better explanations for newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

take a model without relation like that

```
 $this->user = $user->withoutRelations();
```